# Set xPage dateTime picker size

Tags: css, xpages

When I set dateTime picker fixed size it moves calendar icon under the Edit box. How to fix that? Here is my simple xPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    enableModifiedFlag="false" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" style="width:122.0px">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

So how do I set datePicker fixed size and keep the icon inline?

Comment: Your XPage works well for all available themes for Domino version 9.0.1 FP5. Please check if you use a customized theme in your application which might break the default behavior.

Comment: Nothing customized but just Domino 8.5. I thought there is CSS solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a width for dateTime input field instead (Domino 8.5.x only):

```
.xspInputFieldDateTimePicker .dijitTextBox {
    width:90px;
}
```

This error doesn't occur in Domino 9.0.1.